# Accessing local #variable in ngFor

Tags: angular

In Angular 5, how can I set and access the local #variable in this scenario?

```
<div *ngFor="let p of model; index as i">

    <!-- field -->
    <input
        type="text" 
        required
        [(ngModel)]="model[i].ti"
        #ti{{i}}="ngModel"
        #tiRef{{i}}
        id="ti"
        name="ti"
    >

    <!-- counter -->
    <div class="counter">
        {{ (tiRef[i].getAttribute('maxlength')) - tiRef[i].value.length }}
    </div>

    <!-- validation -->
    <div *ngIf="ti[i].touched && !ti[i].valid && ti[i].errors && ti[i].errors.required">
        Please enter a title.
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: you can talk to `#variable`'s by simply referring to their name

Comment: Ok, but how do I refer to their name in the above scenario, where the `#variable`s are created dynamically? `ti[i]` doesn't work. `ti{{i}}` doesn't work either.

Comment: It may not be possible to define template ref variables with names assigned at run time

Comment: the same way you created them i assume, i didnt think you could use non alphanumerical characters in the id name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give simple names to the [template reference variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-), and refer to them as usual. The variables are defined for each iteration of the `ngFor` loop and are available in the context of that iteration (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmo8md) for an example). If the markup is used in a `form` tag, make sure that each `input` field has a unique `name`.

```
<div *ngFor="let p of model; let i=index">

    <input 
      type="text" 
      required 
      [(ngModel)]="p.ti" 
      #ti="ngModel" 
      #tiRef 
      [name]="'ti' + i">

    <div class="counter">
        {{ tiRef.getAttribute('maxlength') - tiRef.value.length }}
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="ti.touched && !ti.valid && ti.errors && ti.errors.required">
        Please enter a title.
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I've tried that. I don't know why, but there is some kind of binding-issue. The `p.ti` value is present in the model, but it does not get displayed in the input field. Yet if I remove the `#ti` and `#tiRef` it works fine. Hence why I want to name these two variables per iteration, to avoid the binding-issue.

Comment: You can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmo8md) that the code works as expected. Check in the console to see if any error is reported and show us how you define the model in the component class. I removed the `id` of the input field because it was not unique (and not used), and I made sure that each input element has a unique `name`.

Comment: Thank you @ConnorsFan, this really helped! The key was to make sure that each `input` element has a unique `name` attribute. Once I used the `[name]="'ti' + i"` syntax from your example, the binding worked correctly!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `ViewChildren`

Below is one way you can try to use it.

```
@ViewChildren('tiChildren') tiChildren: QueryList<any>;

tiChildrenArray: any[] = [];

constructor() {
    tiChildrenArray = this.tiChildren.toArray();
}


<div *ngFor="let p of model; index as i">

    <!-- field -->
    <input
        type="text" 
        required
        [(ngModel)]="p.ti"
        #tiChildren
        id="ti"
        name="ti"
    >

    <!-- counter -->
    <div class="counter">
        {{ (tiChildrenArray[i].getAttribute('maxlength')) - tiChildrenArray[i].value.length }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'toArray' of undefined`

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried adding it to the top of the component, and I also tried adding it to `ngOnInit()` instead. Same error in both cases. `tiChildren` is `undefined`.

Comment: try it in `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: This line `@ViewChildren('tiChildren') tiChildren: QueryList<any>;` doesn't seem to work. `this.tiChildren` is always empty. How does `@ViewChildren` work? Does it automatically refresh (since the data for the ngFor is loaded asynchronously)?

Comment: Yea it is just like `ViewChild` for the loops. It does not matter if the data is sync or async. It should work. Try `setTimeout` 1000, or some button click. Basically, wait until the whole page is loaded and then trigger some function to see the contents of `tiChildren`

Comment: @Dave yea I agree. I just wanted to provide some quick hack. But, your idea sounds better :)

Comment: @Dave Yes, I am doing `this.tiChildrenArray = this.tiChildren.toArray();` in `ngAfterViewInit()`. How and where do I add a `changes()` handler to the `QueryList` and `subscribe` to it?

Comment: @Ben try something like this `let test = this.tiChildren.changes;
    test.subscribe(() => {
      // your code
    });`

Comment: I am trying `ngAfterViewInit() {
        let test = this.tiChildren.changes; 
        test.subscribe(() => { 
            this.tiChildrenArray = this.tiChildren.toArray();
        });        
    }`

Comment: This now populates `tiChildrenArray`, but leads to an error in the html regarding the actual use of `tiChildren` for the counter: `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.`

Comment: @Dave I already wrapped the counter in `*ngIf="tiChildrenArray && tiChildrenArray.length>0"` which is what led to the above error when the value of that expression actually changes from false to true when the data has been loaded.